# Нужна ли колонка amount в соединительнoй таблице многие-ко-многим?

Tags: sql, oracle, таблицы, моделирование

Есть соединительная таблица `(user_id, item_id)`, без `primary key`, так как у пользователя может быть много единиц одного вида `item_id`.

Правильно ли это? Или лучше сделать композитный ключ `(user_id, item_id)`, но добавить колонку `amount`, для записи количества данного предмета?

Comment: А где вы такой термин нашли - ассоциативная таблица?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, лучше добавить колонку `amount` и сделать композитный первичный ключ:

```
create table useritems (
    user_id int references users (id), 
    item_id int references items (id), amount int, 
    constraint pk_useritems primary key (user_id, item_id))
/
```

Если приложение делает подобные запросы - кол-во предмета у всех пользователей:

```
select count (amount) totalitems
from useritems
where item_id = ?
/
```

То композитный индекс не поможет, так как его первая колонка `user_id` не используется.
Добавте просто ещё один дополнительный индекс:

```
create index ix_useritems on useritems (item_id)
/
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас в структуре используются суррогатные ключи, то само то, это сделать:

```
(id, user_id, item_id, amount)
```

где id - первичный ключ, генерируемый базой. Это классическая таблица для связей M:N. Я настоятельно не рекомендую создавать таблицы без первичного ключа.